# Rename-LocalUser is not recognized on Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is the error.

```
Rename-LocalUser : The term 'Rename-LocalUser' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Rename-LocalUser
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Rename-LocalUser:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: What version of PowerShell are you running? That cmdlet is not available in all versions.

Comment: Its Power Shell version 5.

Comment: 5, or 5.1? It's apparently a new cmdlet in 5.1

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Just write the answer and link to the docs. Likely they dont have 5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Rename-LocalUser` cmdlet is [only available in PowerShell 5.1 or later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/rename-localuser?view=powershell-5.1). If you are running on Windows 8 or earlier (or the corresponding Windows Server versions), you will have to [download and install the WMF 5.1 package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616); it is not automatically installed. On Windows 10 (or the corresponding Windows Server version), it *may* be automatically installed with the Fall Creator's Update.